# How can I return the last inserted id in CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Using CodeIgniter 3, I want to get the last auto-incremented id for the insert operation as the return value of my query but it is returning the wrong id greater than 0. Each time the record is inserted into the table, returned value is incremented by 1.

```
function insert($data)
{
    $ip = $this->input->ip_address();
    $this->db->set('application_date',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $this->db->set('created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $this->db->set('created_ip',$ip);
    $this->db->set('update_count', 1, FALSE);
    $this->db->insert(TABLE_CUSTOMER, $this->security->xss_clean($data));
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: @KUMAR Thats just the same thing. OP: what is happening? When you inssert what Id is being returned and inserted?

Comment: each time the record is inserted both inserted id and returned id are different.

Comment: might some error occuring which returning the inserted id  0  try checking error log

Comment: returned id is not 0 but greater than 0